# Finding the output of 2**32 % x in arc4random.c

Tags: c, math

I saw some code (in arc4random.c of libbsd) calculating `2**32 % x`. A cleaned up version is below:

```
uint32_t x;
...
if (x >= 2) {
    /* Calculate (2**32 % x) avoiding 64-bit math */
    if (x > 0x80000000)
        mod_res = 1 + ~x;       /* 2**32 - x */
    else {
        /* (2**32 - (x * 2)) % x == 2**32 % x when x <= 2**31 */
        mod_res = ((0xffffffff - (x * 2)) + 1) % x;
    }
}
```

While the reasoning makes sense, my question is whether are there some obscure reasons not to use a simpler:

```
uint32_t x;
...
if (x >= 2) {
    /* Calculate (2**32 % x) avoiding 64-bit math */
    mod_res = -x % x;
}
```

Comment: Maybe its trying to calculate it while "avoiding 64-bit math".

Comment: `-x % x` is zero for any `x` except 0, isn't it?

Comment: @IgorKorkhov when `x` is `unsigned` `-x` equals `UINT_MAX + 1 - x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won't work on a machine where `int` is larger than 32 bits. In this case, in the expression `-x`, the operand would be promoted to `int` type, and thus become signed. This would cause the result of the expression `-x % x` to always be zero.

This behavior is due to C's integer promotion rules, which state that if an `int` can represent all values of an operand, then that operand will be promoted to an `int`. While this always preserves value, it may change the signedness of the type.

On a compiler with 32-bit `int`s it would work correctly, because `unsigned int` would not be promoted to `int`, and so `-x` would be equal to `2**32 - x`.

Your version can be fixed by casting the promoted value back to unsigned:

```
mod_res = ((uint32_t) -x) % x;
```

[Here is an example](http://www.ideone.com/tU0rv) demonstrating this with a 16-bit type on a machine with 32-bit ints.